# Absorption of light

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, atomic-physics

I have two questions:

1. When an atom absorbs part of spectrum from white light, why doesn't it radiate the photon back? What happens to the photon?
2. How does the wave theory of light explain absorption of light?

Answer (score 6):

If an atom absorbs a photon, an electron will be raised to an excited state. For the relaxation of the excited state, we have basically two possibilities: (1) The electron jumps back to initial state where it started. Thereby it emits the "same" photon (same wavelength) it absorbed initially. However, it doesn't have to be in the same direction as the initial photon. (2) The electron jumps to a different state. Hence, a photon of different wavelength will be emitted.

For you second question look up *Beer–Lambert's law*: It describes an exponential decrease of the intensity.